# What is an OFAC "prohibited transaction"?

Tags: united-states, international, finance, regulations

so obvious first step: the official [OFAC F.A.Q.](https://ofac.treasury.gov/faqs/topic/1501) (i.e. of the U.S. Office of Foreign Assets Control in the U.S. Treasury Department):

> ## 3. What does one mean by the term "prohibited transactions"?
>
> Prohibited transactions are [....] transactions [....] in which U.S. persons may not engage [....]

Great! So "prohibited transactions" are "transactions" which are "prohibited".  Now I just need a *few* *small* clarifications:

- Clearly it is allowed to receive funds from transactions initiated by designated entities, since [celebrities have received over 100 USD (0.1 ETH as of 2023-07-07)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83284/what-are-the-consequences-of-being-party-to-a-ofac-prohibited-transaction) [without concequences.](https://blog.chainalysis.com/reports/tornado-cash-ofac-sanction-trolls/) (unless OFAC regulations are selectively enforced for discriminatory purposes)
- How about if my online store initiates a financial transaction to receive funds from an an OFAC designated individual and then before completing the *store* transaction (as distinct from the *financial* transaction) realize they are on the SDN list.  Am I fine so long as I do not refund the transaction?
- Could I refund the original debit/credit card transaction (i.e. the refund is performed without creating a second transaction, i.e. the original transaction ends in a refunded state instead of in a captured state)?
- Could I refund the original transaction with a separate transaction? (I would assume that it is not allowed.)
- Are OFAC regulations publicly available or are they private internal regulations that are themselves only loosely and indirectly limited in scope by laws and the executive branch (and thus [without regard to constitutional limits](https://www.aclu.org/cases/kindhearts-charitable-humanitarian-development-inc-v-geithner-et-al?redirect=cpredirect/38636) <s>like</s> <s>a rouge</s> <s>the C.I.A.</s> <s>many 3-5 letter government agencies</s>, since the constitution now has no more effective value than toilet paper apparently.)?

Comment: Please spell out any acronym used the first time it is used in the future. I edited the post to do so this time.

Comment: "Are OFAC regulations publicly available" Yes.